# Filter logs in logstash and save to Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elk

I am dumping all my logs into Elastic Search.
It looks like.
[image]

Now I want :

1. Only limited fields should be pushed to ES.
2. Parse message part and add another field `log.level:` and save the value INFO/DEBUG/ERROR from the message field.

Can anyone help me to do that. I am new to Elastic.

My logstash.conf is

```
 input {
      beats {
        port => 5044
       }
    }
 
output {
        if [agent][hostname]=="TEST-PC"{
                elasticsearch {
                        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
                        manage_template => false
                        index => "INDEXNAME"
                        user => "elastic"
                        password => "password"
              }
          }     
      }
```

Comment: Please show your existing Logstash configuration file.

Comment: @Val Added the configuration the description now. Please check!

Comment: Could you paste in some logs which you need to filter ?You can use `grok` filter of logstash to filter out the necessary field you need.

Answer (score 0):

Add this filter section to your logstash config file.

```
filter {
      grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}\s\[%{NOTSPACE:Meta}\]\s%{WORD:Logtype}\s%{GREEDYDATA:Log_Message}" }
      }
      if "INFO" in [Logtype] {
          drop{}
      }
  }
```